# Extern a function declared and defined locally

Tags: c

I have two **c** files:

**main.c**

```
int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

**foo.c**

```
void foo(void);

void foo(void)
{ 
    printf("Hi");
}
```

Since all functions are `extern` by default then why can't **main.c** find `foo()`?
The function prototype -> `void foo(void);` is not declared in **foo.h**, It remains in **foo.c**

I get an error :

> *undefined reference to foo*

when compiling this code.

Comment: "why cant main.c know foo()?" --> `main()` _can_ know about `foo()`.  `main()` just needs a correct declaration.

Comment: I get a build error..whats wrong in the code?

Comment: How are you trying to build?  If you just compile `main.c`, it will work.  But if you try to compile *and* link to build an executable without including `foo.o`, it will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C source files are compiled independently. E.g. when the compiler is working on `main.c`, it knows nothing about what is in `foo.c` or any other file, unless you actually reference some other file.

Comment: So there is no other way, than moving the prototype of foo() to foo.h and using foo.h in Main.c

Comment: There are other ways. You could manually declare `foo()` in both files, but then you run the risk of making a mistake and having the declarations be different, in which case the linker would complain. Or you could (but you really shouldn't) rely on the default prototype that the compiler gives an undeclared function.

Comment: The code above built with warnings. I had not included the file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are no major problems with your code (tough some might argue that the warnings given below are "major").  You're probably just not building correctly.  But you can build with:

```
$ gcc -c main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:4:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘foo’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     foo();
     ^~~
$ gcc -c foo.c
foo.c: In function ‘foo’:
foo.c:7:6: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      printf("Hi");
      ^~~~~~
foo.c:7:6: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
foo.c:7:6: note: include ‘<stdio.h>’ or provide a declaration of ‘printf’
$ gcc main.o foo.o
$ ./a.out
Hi$
```

Comment: im using code blocks and its giving me an error

Comment: Yes. solved. Getting warnings now. Not errors. Had not correctly included the file.